# Using Curl to get a Https webpage in Windows 7

Tags: windows, perl, curl, cygwin, libcurl

I just need to fetch an https page, and I'm using curl currently by having the curl.exe application in my Path and calling it with a Perl file. However, then I get the error "* Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl". I've been looking around and I can't find a solid set of instructions to get it to work. I have installed cygwin, and OpenSSL-Win32 but something tells me I'm going to have to compile curl from scratch. I have no experience with this. How do you do it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found the below steps worked well

1. Download and unzip 64-bit [cURL with SSL](http://curl.download.nextag.com/download/curl-7.21.7-win64-ssl-sspi.zip).
2. Download the [latest bundle of Certficate Authority Public Keys](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) from mozilla.org.
3. Rename this file from cacert.pem to curl-ca-bundle.crt
4. Make sure both of them are in the `PATH` environment.

Test

```
curl -L https://www.google.com
```

**UPDATE**

If you are open to try other tools, I think [httpie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie) is also a good alternative.

Comment: thanks so much - this worked fine and dandy for me. I had to use the -k option for the parse cloud tutorial. (On the off chance anybody else uses parse AND is a windows brother)

Comment: Worked for me using **Cygwin** to clone my private gist repo from GitHub, but at step 3 I had to rename the file to `ca-bundle.crt` and put it in the `/usr/ssl/certs/` directory.

Comment: Your first link now gives a 404.

Answer (score 6):

```
curl --insecure
```

If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.