# libcurl on windows

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am writing a C++ application that needs to use libcurl with HTTPS support. I already built the basic libcurl without any problem. However I have spent over 10 hours on compiling the HTTPS version, I've tried building it with VS2008, I've tried with mingw32 and I've tried with nmake. I have read about every post there is on the subject and nothing seems to work on my computer.

My question is the following : Since I use the curl lib without modifications, Is there anywhere I can find a package containing : libcurl.lib, libcurl.dll, and all the necessary dlls (ssl,zlib, libeay32,etc) to include them in my project and never worry about compilation ever again??

The lib absolutely needs to have SSL support.

Thanks

David

Comment: I'm wondering if the downloads from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html are fine for you? They have prebuilt SSL-enabled libcurl for windows (generic, cygwin, msvc) as well as a link to a site to get [OpenSSL binaries for windows](http://www.shininglightpro.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Comment: It only took me 6 hours to build libcurl and prereqs on Windows. As I recall the tricky bits were making sure every project used the same compiler settings for multithread, and of course doing the proper Perl stuff to build OpenSSL. I absolutely *had* to build OpenSSL, no prebuilt libraries worked.

Comment: Zan : Maybe that is my problem, I use the prebuilt SSL lib. I'll try that option tonight, thanks
birryree : I tried those but I had linking errors, maybe it's related to Zan's comment.

Comment: @ David im facing this problem too. What is your solution?

Comment: I built everything myself, no more prebuilt lib

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Curl to get a Https webpage in Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562095/using-curl-to-get-a-https-webpage-in-windows-7)