# How do I "add https support" to cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

About to attend a course and a requirement is a laptop with `linux` or `cygwin`

Another is

*cygwin requires https support to be installed*

This is likely because I will need to use `cUrl` to fetch `https` pages

So I installed and updated `cygwin` to latest, but cannot find anywhere how to "install https support"

**UPDATE**

1. downloaded certificates from mozilla as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13105921/562459
2. exported proxy settings - needs to go in the .bashrc or similar

```
export http_proxy=http://nameofyourproxy:xxxx/  
export https_proxy=http://nameofyourproxy:xxxx/
```

where xxxx is the proxy port number

you need BOTH http and https if not you get

> curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'www.google.com'

when you do

> curl -L https://www.google.com

**UPDATE 2**

I needed to export https too of course and I needed to put the certs in the right place.

```
CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

So I renamed the download to ca-bundle.crt and copied it to

```
<install path>cygwin\usr\ssl\certs
```

and that was it.

Comment: Error message from `curl -v https://www.google.com`?

Comment: In cygwin, I wouldn't expect this `/windows/system32/curl-ca-bundle.crt`. Instead, I'd expect something like this: `/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/curl-ca-bundle.crt`

Comment: Windows path is *probably* something like `c:\cygwin\usr\ssl\...` Cygwin path is *probably* something like `/usr/ssl/...` or `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/usr/ssl/...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. You need to ask somebody for clarification.

If you're expected to run Apache on your laptop, you need a certificate. Search online for "configure Apache https". [Here's one search result](http://www.onlamp.com/2008/03/04/step-by-step-configuring-ssl-under-apache.html).

But if, for example, you're expected to use cURL to fetch pages using https, I think you just need to [install some public keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13105921/562459). I don't think you need the most recent version of cURL, as the linked answer implies, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I was having a totally different problem, because I couldn't clone my private gist from GitHub.com using Cygwin due to -maybe- wrong or expired default ca-certificates. So I replaced the default one with the given one from the 2nd answer you linked and now it works perfectly !!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Little late, but: If you're using cygwin, all you need to do is start the cygwin terminal as administrator, and then run:

`update-ca-trust`

This will fetch and store the certificates in the correct location.

Comment: Yeah - 3.5 years later it is no longer an issue

Comment: Thank you, your answer saved me lots of time.